# recognize opera browser by php

Tags: php, css, browser, opera

i using this php code for recognize browsers.

```
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match("/\bOpera\b/i", $ua)==TRUE){
    echo '<link href="stili/opera.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>';
}elseif(preg_match("/\bMSIE\b/i", $ua)==TRUE){
    echo '<link href="stili/ie.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>';
}elseif(preg_match("/\bSafari\b/i", $ua)==TRUE){
    echo '<link href="stili/safari.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>';
}elseif(preg_match("/\bFirefox\b/i", $ua)==TRUE){
    echo '<link href="stili/moz.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>';
}else
    echo '<link href="stili/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>';
```

Works for all browsers, but not work whit Opera. How to solve?

Comment: 1. use http://us2.php.net/get_browser, 2. Write proper css and you wont need to do this.

Comment: I got this error
Warning: get_browser() [function.get-browser]: browscap ini directive not set in C:\AppServ\www\test.php on line 4

Comment: http://us2.php.net/get_browser#refsect1-function.get-browser-notes it's good to read the documentation, mate

Comment: Browser sniffing to solve CSS issues is bad. What is the real problem you're trying to solve? And for which version of Opera?

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to use the PHP function get_browser() ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php )

```
<?php
$browser = get_browser(null, true);

echo $browser["browser"];
?>
```

Comment: got this error

Warning: get_browser() [function.get-browser]: browscap ini directive not set in C:\AppServ\www\test.php on line 2

Comment: You need to set browsercap directive in your php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

its not mandatory that opera useragent  string will have word opera in it.
http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Opera/